# Suitable compiled language for new project

Tags: programming-languages, project

I'm about to develop some commercial software that will run on OSX and Linux. The program will be doing some heavy string manipulation, base64 encoding, zlib compression and may require http libraries in the future.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Many thanks in advance, 
Toby.

Comment: Doesn't your knowledge of the language have some bearing on this? If I suggest C++, are you going to take three months or so to learn enough to produce competent code?

Comment: I'm familiar with C++, Python, Objective C and Java - but learning a new language is always fun. :)

Comment: I'd suggest python (given your current knowledge)

Comment: Unfortunately I cant use Python - It's too easy to de-compile.

Comment: Python?  I thought it was a pig on CPU-intensive tasks.  Just sayin'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++.

std::string and [boost::regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/regex) for the string manipulation. zlib has both C and C++ bindings. You might like [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) for no-GUI HTTP stuff. Use a cross-platform GUI toolkit (I suggest wxWidgets or Qt) if you need windows.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest [Ruby](http://Ruby-Lang.Org/). Its string manipulation isn't quite up to Perl's or ELisp's standards, but reasonably close and base64, ZLib and HTTP are part of the standard library. And it runs on pretty much every platform under the sun, including Windows, OSX, Linux, Unix, JVM, CLI and Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, I'd say Java. It's cross platform and has all the features you require.